# Jquery get clicked text dropdown menu bootstrap

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and i have the following dropdown menu :

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                 number of rooms
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >5</a>
                    </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want to get the selected text when i click on an entry of the drop down menu.
I've tried :

```
$('.dropdown-menu :selected').text();
$('.dropdown-menu option:selected').text();
$('.dropdown-menu').find('option:selected').text();
$('.dropdown-menu li a').text(); //returns 12345
$('.dropdown-menu > .active').text();
...
```

but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong ? Thx

**EDIT** In fact i am totally new to Javascript (i'm a java developper). I am using Backbone and would like to have something like that :

```
window.RoomView = Backbone.View.extend({

events : {
    "click .dropdown-menu"       : "test"
}

test : function(){
//display selected text
}
```

Comment: Where does `:selected` or `.active` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"click .dropdown-menu a"    : "displayRoomConfigForms"

displayRoomConfigForms: function(event){
  var text = $(event.currentTarget).text(); 
}
```

made it

Answer (score 7):

It depends on whether you mean you want to get the text within an existing function, or just at all:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click( function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

I'm not a backbone expert, but perhaps...

```
events : {
    "click .dropdown-menu a"       : "test"
}

test : function(){
    //display selected text
    var text = $(this).text();
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, could you give me the code to retrieve the text within an existing function plz ?

Answer (score 2):

Just do that.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: `funciton()` -> `function()`